# How to add list elements "tags in cs_instance" if a variable is defined

Tags: ansible

I am creating instances using the CloudStack  module [cs_instance](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/cs_instance_module.html), for example:

```
- name: create or update instance
  cs_instance:
    display_name: web-vm-1
    template: Linux Debian 7 64-bit
    service_offering: Tiny
    ssh_key: john@example.com
    tags:
      - { key: admin, value: john }
      - { key: group, value: "{{ vm_group_tab }}" }
    user_data: |
        #cloud-config
        packages:
          - nginx
```

How could I add or remove `tags` if a variable is defined or not, for example, if variable `vm_group_tab` is undefined I would just like to have:

```
    tags:
      - { key: admin, value: john }
```

If variable `vm_group_tab` is defined:

```
    tags:
      - { key: admin, value: john }
      - { key: group, value: "{{ vm_group_tab }}" }
```

As a workaround currently I am setting var to null `vm_group_tab: ~` but the tag is been created as `group: None` any ideas how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
tags: >
  {{ [dict(key='admin',value='john')] + 
     ([dict(key='group',value=vm_group_tab|d(''))] if vm_group_tab|d('') != '' else [])
  }}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am giving a try but having `vm_group_tab: ~` still adding the group and if I set `vm_group_tab: ""` remove all the tags not just the one with name `group`

Comment: working now but had to default to `vm_group_tab: ""` also wondering if could be reduced to: `([dict(key='group', value=vm_group_tab)] if vm_group_tab|d('') != '' else [])` only using `vm_group_tab|d('') !=''` or any reason to also put it in the value ?

Comment: both parts of if/else is templated before condition is being checked, so if `vm_group_tab` is undefined, you'll get exception...